# Twilio statuscallback not working

Tags: twilio-api

I have created a statuscallback url for Twilio SMS.
But am getting this exception

> org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: It is invalid to call isReady() when the response has not been put into non-blocking mode (through reference chain: org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade["outputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream["ready"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: It is invalid to call isReady() when the response has not been put into non-blocking mode (through reference chain: org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade["outputStream"]->org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream["ready"])
>       org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:292)
>       org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:100)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:231)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
>       org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
>       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method

My code is as below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getstatus",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object getTwilioStatusCallback( HttpServletRequest httpRequest, final  HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse){
//  System.out.println(httpRequest.getParameter("MessageSid"));
     httpServletResponse.setStatus(httpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT);
    return  httpServletResponse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First it looks like you are doing a synchronous call, which is a nono in web development. Second, your parameter as MessageSid.. Twilio is notorious for not having the correct reference in their documents. Try messageSid as a parameter. I had the same problem in Node. 
You can also look at the entire request body and see how it shows up and get the correct parameter from there, which is what I had to do.
Hopefully this helps.